# Figure title in List of Figures

Tags: floats, captions

I've got a figure which has several annotations on-image. The figure caption explains these:

```
\caption{Image of my item. (1) Part of the item. (2) Another notable part of the item. (3) Yet another part. (4) The final part of the item.
```

The `List of Figures` uses the entire caption, which looks slightly silly. Ideally I'd like to use half the `\caption` text, excluding the annotation explanations.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use the optional `\caption` argument: `\caption[LoF caption]{Long text caption}`

```
\caption[Short caption for LoF]
  {Image of my item. (1) Part of the item. %
   (2) Another notable part of the item. %
   (3) Yet another part. %
   (4) The final part of the item.}
```