# List of figures \hbox overfull

Tags: table-of-contents

I have an overfull `\hbox` in my list of figures, not because of long captions/page number over run, which is addressed in other postings(addressed in [Fix formatting errors of page number > 99 in table of contents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127643/fix-formatting-errors-of-page-number-99-in-table-of-contents) and [Figure title in List of Figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66020/figure-title-in-list-of-figures), but because the figure number (left hand side of the listing) is too long.  Below is a few lines from the `.lof` file. It is only the last three figures that generate an error. Figures 4.6.8 and 4.6.9 generate no overfull box but 4.6.10,4.6.11,4.6.12 all do.

```
\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {4.6.8}{\ignorespaces Repeat: Model \& Data: Detail}}{164}{figure.4.6.8}

\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {4.6.9}{\ignorespaces High School GPA: Model \& Data}}{165}{figure.4.6.9}

\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {4.6.10}{\ignorespaces Math SAT Score: Model \& Data}}{166}{figure.4.6.10}

\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {4.6.11}{\ignorespaces Timing: Model \& Data}}{167}{figure.4.6.11}

\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {4.6.12}{\ignorespaces sequencing of Physics 7A Effect by Course}}{168}{figure.4.6.12}
```

Harish Kumar provided a solution. Much thanks

Comment: Can you add a mwe please?

Comment: Put `\usepackage{tocloft}` in the preamble and `\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{4em}` Change `4em` suitably.

Comment: This is a duplicate; let me try to find the appropriate question.

Comment: this question deals with too-wide elements that precede things like captions and section titles.  it should be more relevant than the cited "duplicate" that deals with page numbers.  [Roman chapter numbers cause overfull hbox in titletoc-ToC](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66289/579)

Comment: From a very short look, i think [this solution on LaTeX-community](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=85013#p85013) might be worth a look. If it does not help, please prepare an [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: @HarishKumar: Do you want to provide an answer or shall we close this?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer As the linked possible duplicate uses `titletoc` and since it does not deal with figure number width, I think I will add an answer hoping that this will add one more landing point.

Answer (score 4):

The tweaking needs of the table of contents are well fulfilled with the package `tocloft`. You can add the line `\usepackage{tocloft}` in the preamble and then adjust the space reserved for type setting the figure number by

```
 \setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{4em}
```

Adjust `4em` as suitable for your needs.