# Listings titles in List of Listings

Tags: table-of-contents, listings, captions

I have a question analogous to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66020/figure-title-in-list-of-figures), but for listings instead of figures.

In my TeX file, I have multiple listings defined as follows:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={A really, really, really, really, really long caption}]
<code>
\end{lstlisting}
```

Now, my List of Listings uses the entire caption, which looks slightly silly. Is there a way to define a short caption for the LoL just like the `\caption[short caption]{long caption}` command for the LoF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the manual page 34:

> `caption={[⟨short⟩]⟨caption text⟩}`
>
> The caption is made of `\lstlistingname` followed by a running number, a seperator, and `⟨caption text⟩`. Either the caption text or, if present, `⟨short⟩` will be used for the list of listings.

So in your case:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={[short caption]{long caption}}]
<code>
\end{lstlisting}
```

Should do.

Note the `{}` wrapping the `caption` argument to avoid the closing `]` to be interpreted as "end of optional argument for `lstlisting`.

Comment: Thank you! Small correction: Your closing brackets are slightly off. It needs to be `[caption={[short caption]{long caption}}]`.

Comment: yes, corrected =)